# Export PDF or Excel file from Crystal Reports using save dialog

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm currently using this code, How to use save dialog to implement at this code. 
I also tried this: `Dim path As String = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(SaveFileDialog.FileName)`

```
Try
   Dim CrExportOptions As CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportOptions
   Dim CrDiskFileDestinationOptions As New  _
   CrystalDecisions.Shared.DiskFileDestinationOptions()
   Dim CrFormatTypeOptions As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.PdfRtfWordFormatOptions()
   CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "c:/crystalExport.pdf"
   CrExportOptions = crypt.ExportOptions
      With CrExportOptions
          .ExportDestinationType = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
          .ExportFormatType = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
          .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions
          .FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions
      End With
      crypt.Export()
  Catch ex As Exception
  End Try
```

Comment: since you are making us guess what the problem is, I'll go with some sort of access denied/path not found error?

Comment: thanks for the comment but I already solve my problem, I used save dialog to get the path the I passed it to my  CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName

Comment: @TopOut you should close your question or add a detail answer and answer your own question.